# Swift: Calling impure function with another function

Tags: function, swift, functional-programming, nested, closures

I am attempting to use a helper function to call an input context sensitive function within the same context. Within the context of a class function called 'drawGrid()' I have the following code and the end bracket of drawGrid() seen in the image. I call input impure 'drawLine()' with 'drawQ1Line()'. I call 'drawQ1Line()' within the context that drawLine() is defined. Perhaps even if this is logical, it is not something inferenced by the Swift language and I need to know how to handle nested calls properly.

I looked up the specific error that I received and found some advice on using closures. To my understanding, closures are essentially functions with state, however, I am not sure if the restrictions on input/output purity is the same or how exactly it relates at the class level. That didn't seem to be the solution to my problem, however, since I am not necessarily interested in keeping state, but rather simply using a helper function to call another. In fact, I am curious if 'shape' and 'pathToDraw' can be called normally as they currently are rather than being stored in a closure as state, even if that would be a fix to my current error. What if I com across a case where I need to call a function in place of SKShapeNode() which depends on input, the value changes, or has output impurity? Then just saving the value won't work.

[image]

Comment: Swift is not (yet) Pascal or Modula - nested functions are not fully implemented. You can have a nested function that refers to 'super' function scope variables, but not other 'sister' functions. I really don't see why other than "it's difficult to implement". It seems inconsistent with Swift's aims...

Answer (score 0):

Swift is a stupid language :-( Use unique names across you internal `func` parameters. Like

```
func drawQ1Line(heightA:CGFLoat, xA:CGFloat, x2A:CGFloat....
  drawLine(xA, hegihtA- ...
```

I tried with this code in Playground:

```
class A {
  func a(a:Int) {
    println(a)
  }
  func b(b:Int) {
    a(b)
  }
}
let a=A()
a.b(1)
```

while

```
class A {
  func a(a:Int) {
    println(a)
  }
  func b(a:Int) {
    a(a)
  }
}
```

throws a compiler error

Comment: Down voting doesn't change the fact that Swift is a stupid language, though.

Comment: You can't call "sister" functions. Your answer is wrong. I do not disagree that one *should* be able to call sister functions.

Comment: @Grimxn Well, I tried that in Playground and it worked. The sister function _is_ called.

Comment: apologies. Your expanded answer is correct - sister functions can be called, but only if they do not reference shared-scope variables.

Comment: That's just one reason why I call Swift a stupid language. 30 years ago in compiler construction we developed better language constructs. Though its better than Obj-C (I will not miss `[ ]`) its concepts seem to neglect almost anything developed ever since thereby introducing new silly concepts.